# iOS retains views tree on hit testing?

Tags: iphone, ios, retain, hittest

I have a "mysterious" retain in my app and I was able to reproduce it in simplification.
I have a view hierarchy as follows:

- Base view (UIView) :

  - Main view (UIView) :

    - Button1 (UIRectButton)
  - Kind-of side menu (UIView) :

    - Button2 (UIRectButton)

When I press **button1** new view of class *MyView* (let's name it **view with image**) is created and added as subview to **Main view**. *MyView* is direct subclass of *UIView* and only custom thing it does is tracking retains, releases and autoreleases (calling *super*, ofcourse). So **view with image** is retained and it's OK.

After that I press **button2**. Here is where "mystery" occurs.

When I touch button, before any callback I can think of, including *touchesBegan*, is called, **view with image** is retained once more. Call stack shows it is something from system hit testing. And no release follows. Nor autorelease.

Tested on iOS 5 simulator and device.

Looks like I overlooking something. What am I doing wrong?

***Edit:***

Found that that odd retain would not spoil anything, and will be released by iOS when appropriate, for example when setting a superview (new one or the same) to view. But I still wonder, for what reason does second retain occur?